# How to send GtkWidgets to the back or front?

Tags: c, layout, gtk

I wonder if there is a way to "Send to back" or "Bring to front" a GtkWidget dynamically. ( I know, it can be done by changing the creating order of GtkWidget )

example : (GTK+ 2.0, Cent OS 7.0, C)

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )    
{
GtkWidget *window, *button1, *button2, *fixed;

gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL); 
button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("A button");
button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("B button");

fixed = gtk_fixed_new();

gtk_fixed_put( (GtkFixed*)fixed,button2, 30, 30 );
gtk_fixed_put( (GtkFixed*)fixed,button1, 50, 50 );
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed);

gtk_widget_show_all (window);
gtk_main ();
return 0;
} 

this program will display : (the first picture)
```

[image: A Button is over B Button]
Are there some commands that can make the "B Button" be in front of "A Button". ( look likes this following picture --> the second picture )

[image: B Button is over A Button]

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve? I fail to see what kind of interface you are building and how achieving this would be useful. Could you please also explicit the version of GTK+ you are using?

Comment: I wouldn't look twice at a program that does something like this.

Comment: The program I write will display the result of first picture, and I want to find the command to achieve the result of second picture. thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there aren't "functions" like those in a GtkFixed.

From the [Gtk 2 documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkFixed.html):

> ### Description
>
> The GtkFixed widget is a container which can place child widgets at
>   fixed positions and with fixed sizes, given in pixels. GtkFixed
>   performs no automatic layout management.
>
> For most applications, you should not use this container! It keeps you
>   from having to learn about the other GTK+ containers, but it results
>   in broken applications. With GtkFixed, the following things will
>   result in truncated text, overlapping widgets, and other display bugs:
>
> - Themes, which may change widget sizes.
> - Fonts other than the one you used to write the app will of course change the size of widgets containing text; keep in mind that users
>     may use a larger font because of difficulty reading the default, or
>     they may be using Windows or the framebuffer port of GTK+, where
>     different fonts are available.
> - Translation of text into other languages changes its size. Also, display of non-English text will use a different font in many cases.
>
> In addition, the fixed widget can't properly be mirrored in
>   right-to-left languages such as Hebrew and Arabic. i.e. normally GTK+
>   will flip the interface to put labels to the right of the thing they
>   label, but it can't do that with GtkFixed. So your application will
>   not be usable in right-to-left languages.
>
> Finally, fixed positioning makes it kind of annoying to add/remove GUI
>   elements, since you have to reposition all the other elements. This is
>   a long-term maintenance problem for your application.
>
> **If you know none of these things are an issue for your application,
>   and prefer the simplicity of GtkFixed, by all means use the widget.
>   But you should be aware of the tradeoffs**.

The order by which they are added is the order they will keep in the virtual Z axis. You can control this by removing and readding them or other similar approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You gave me a really important hint. I found I can simply resolve this problem by removing the widget form container, and then adding that back. 

    gtk_widget_ref(GTK_WIDGET(button1));
    gtk_container_remove( GTK_CONTAINER(fixed), button1);
    gtk_fixed_put( (GtkFixed*)fixed,button1,50,50 );